# Destroy Specific Python Widgets Using Instance Number?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a button to put 10 buttons on a canvas.
when I run the button once, it makes the canvas and the ten buttons.

```
    for a in range(10):
        b=Button(canvas, text=str(a) + "but", font=A12B,
                 command=lambda : noButs())
        b.pack(side='right')

    def noButs():
        b.destroy()
```

however, if I click twice, it makes twenty buttons, and it will not destroy any of them.

Is there a way to remove specific widgets by name, or instance number??
or maybe get the number of the active canvas and destroy it?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the buttons in a list, and then you can destroy them by index.
Something like:

```
buttons = []
for a in range(10):
    b=Button(canvas, text=str(a) + "but", font=A12B,
             command=lambda : noButs())
    b.pack(side='right')
    buttons.append(b)

def noButs():
    for button in buttons:
        button.destroy()
        buttons = []

def deleteBut(index):
    buttons[index].destroy()
    del buttons[index]
```

Note that this changes the index for items after the one you delete.

If you prefer, you can use a dictionary, and give each button a name.

Just make sure you don't put buttons = [] every time you push your button. Do it outside of the button action (if you use a class add self.buttons).